# Code navigation in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, code-navigation

I find it difficult to navigate through code for a big project involving many classes, XML files, SQL files etc.

I know <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to open resources, but thats where my little knowledge ends.  How can I easily navigate through a hell of Java and non-Java files in Eclipse with just keyboard.  Most of you gurus already will have a list of favorite code navigation shortcuts/tips, I suppose.

Please share.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.allapplabs.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm

Comment: You may want to look at [What's your favourite hotkey in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98220/what-is-your-favorite-hot-key-in-eclipse) and [Is it possible to work in Eclipse with keyboard only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605644/is-it-possible-to-work-in-eclipse-with-keyboard-only) for inspiration.  And/or make this community wiki as there's no single correct answer.

Comment: ALT + SHIFT + W + P can also be very useful to find already open classes (for example with CTRL + SHIFT + R) in your package explorer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try these shortcuts:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> for opening any resources

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> for switching between open windows

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> for opening loaded classes

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> for opening type hierarchy

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> for viewing all the methods in a class / interface. Pressing this again shows you all the superclass methods too.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to run a previously run class.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>J</kbd> for running a class as Java Application.

Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when clicking on a method / class / interface opens it.

Also check out the Java Browsing perspective.

Answer (score 8):

F3 : Go to the declaration / definition of method / variable

Cmd + [ : Go back

Cmd + ] : Go Forward

Cmd + 1 : Quick Fix

Cmd + T : Shows Class Hierarchy

Cmd + Shift + o : Fix Missing Imports

Cmd + / : Comment / Uncomment code

Cmd + Shift + / : Comment/ Uncomment  with block comment

Cmd + L : Go to Line

Cmd + Shift + F : Auto Formatting

Cmd + D : Delete Line

Ctrl + Q : Go to To Last Edited Place

Cmd + Shift + G : Search the Workspace for references to the selected method or variable

Cmd + Shift + R: Open any file quickly without browsing for it in the Package Explorer:

Cmd + Shift + T: Open a type (e.g.: a class, an interface) . Unlike the previous shortcut, this even works when you don’t have the Java source file in your workspace

Cmd+Shift + P : Find Closing Brace.

Fn + Option + Del : Delete next word

Option + Del : Delete previous word

Shift + Fn + Cmd + Del : Delete to the end of the line

Shift + Cmd + Del: Delete to the start of the line

Shift + Cmd + L : List all Eclipse Keyboard Shortcuts

Cmd + K : Find Next

Shift + Cmd + K : Find previous

Cmd + Enter : Insert line above

Shift  + Cmd + Enter : Insert a line below

Alt + Shift + R : Renames  variables / methods / classes, renaming the class files if necessary. Also fixes all references

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + Left Arraow -- Goes back (just like in a browser)

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + Right Arraow -- Goes forward

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> -- Goes to the last edited line of code

Also a usefeul tip when looking for classes is to press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and partially type the name of the class/interface/enum that you look for.
For instance, if you were to look for a class named StringParserHelper, you could type
SPH, or StrPH, or String*Hel, or *ParH. Exercise with the combinations. This will help you allot.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>  Goes to next problem (compilation error or warning)
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>  Goes to previous problem (compilation error or warning)

There are many useful shortcuts. You can look at them by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.
Press it twice and you will be edit the keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

Navigating code with Eclipse, using the keyboard? Here are some shortcuts I use with high frecuency:

- <kbd>F3</kbd>: while on a class name, a method name, or a variable reference, it opens the selected element declaration.
- <kbd>F4</kbd>: Opens the type hierarchy view for the selected element (a class, or method...)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: search and open a Java Type (note that it won't search on JSPs, XML files, etc. only will search the classes declared)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>: Opens a dropdown with the list of open files (so you can change from one to another).
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>: Dropdown with the available views. It allows you to switch from code editor to the Navigator view (so you can open other files)

There are lot more, but I use thess few continually

Answer (score 0):

To add up a few

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> - To organize imports

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> - To get suggestions on a specific line